# Mac OS Partition Invisible in BootCamp Windows 7

Tags: macos, boot-camp

I upgraded my Mac OS system from Yosemite to macOS High Sierra, and found that the Mac OS partition became invisible in the Boot Camp Windows. I re-installed Boot Camp drivers in Windows but still did not solve it.

How to make the Mac OS Partition visible again in Boot Camp Windows?

Comment: Can windows read the High Sierra partition format? If not, then it won’t or may not be visible. Also why does windows need to see it - as long as it knows where its own partition starts and finishes it should be fine. As for shared files then a third partition can be a solution...

Answer (score 0):

If the upgrade to High Sierra caused a conversion to the new APFS format, then Windows will not be able to read the converted Mac volumes. Also, you will not be able to boot back to macOS directly from Windows. Currently, Apple does not offer a fix to this problem.